# Problems of getting data from remote database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to fetch data from server database with node.js

code:

```
const start = async () => {
    let oldDB = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://url:27017/datatool' , { useMongoClient: true, user: 'datahub', pass: 'HappyPetter321' });
    const clients = await oldDB.model('clientaccount', OldClientSchema).find({});
    console.log(JSON.stringify(clients,undefined,2));
    console.log(`obtained ${clients.length} records from database.`);}
start();
```

actually, I got some data like that:

```
[
{
"_id": "5b938e2ef2cd6880f44d120c",
....,
....,
},
{...},
{...}
]
```

But the strange thing is that when I tried `db.getCollection('clientaccount').find({{"_id" : ObjectId("5b938e2ef2cd6880f44d120c")}})`in Robo 3T which also connected to the same database, the result is `Fetched 0 record(s) in 15ms`.
Does anybody have ideas about it?

Comment: Here your _id field seems to be a string, not an ObjectId

Comment: @matthPen   nope. It is  ObjectID type

Comment: typo in query : db.getCollection('clientaccount').find({"_id" : ObjectId("5b938e2ef2cd6880f44d120c")})